# Passing JSON data to server via query string in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, json, google-chrome

I am using a $.getJSON call to pass JSON data from a mobile client (like a tablet) to an ashx handler on a remote cross-domain server. Note that $.getJSON call is mandatory inside the architecture.

The full code would be like

```
$.getJSON('http://www.domain.com/Proxy.ashx?json=' + JSON.stringify(json) + '&callback=?', function (result) {
....                
        });
```

It seems that Chrome limit for query string size is 65535 characters. Is this still true, and also for the mobile browser (android)? It seems a fair amount of data, especially if I compress JSON data before the call, but might eventually become problematic.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

65K is about right for Chrome on Android and Chrome but **you really should not be passing this much data over a GET request**.  It is a very bad practice.

Instead use a POST. If you own the domain that the request is going to you can set it up to use [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) (Cross Origin resource sharing) that will allow you to make the POST request across domains.  If you don't own the domain you will have to proxy the requests through your server or one like http://www.corsproxy.com/

Comment: Hi Kinlan - that's exactly what I did before reading your answer. I also think that is a way to go, much better than using JSONP for cross-domain requests with a lot of posted data. Thanks for your time.